# @StringDef lint doesn't seem to work

Tags: java, android, android-studio, annotations, lint

I am creating a custom annotation for firebase events. My inspiration comes from [official android docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/annotation/StringDef.html) and other `@StringDef` annotations. It looks like this:

```
@Retention(SOURCE)
@StringDef({
        EVENT_1, EVENT_2
})
@Size(max = 32) // firebase limit
public @interface UserActivityEvents {

    String EVENT_1 = "ev_1";
    String EVENT_2 = "really_long_event_name_that_exceeds_32_chars_limit";
    ...

}
```

The class that encapsulates the logging is defined as follows:

```
public class UserActivityEvent {

    private @UserActivityEvents String eventName;

    private UserActivityEvent() {

    }

    public UserActivityEvent(@UserActivityEvents String eventName) {
        this.eventName = eventName;
    }

    ...

}
```

The problem is that the AS lint is never triggered, no matter what I specify in the constructor, even if I do something like this:

```
new UserActivityEvent("asd");
```

My expectations for `@UserActivityEvents` are:

1. The parameter in constructor of `UserActivityEvent` can only be one of the strings defined in @StringDef
2. Event length doesn't exceed the 32 chars limit
3. If one of these rules are violated, the code is underlined (classic AS error highlight) and the error message is displayed when hovering over the code.

Edit: I found out that if I define a new event `EVENT_3` in `UserActivityEvents` but don't include it in `@UserActivityEvents` and I try to reference it as `new UserActivityEvent(UserActivityEvents.EVENT_3)`, the lint is properly triggered and says this: "Must be one of: EVENT_1, EVENT_2 or length must be at most 32". In case of using `new UserActivityEvent("asd")` it doesn't work

Comment: after further troubleshooting, we figured out that `@Size` annotation suppresses the `@StringDef` annotation, so it's not possible to use both at once. It's not really an answer since it might actually be a bug or there is another workaround, so I am posting this as a comment.